# Why does \maketitle change the availability of \@title?

Tags: header-footer, titles, scrpage2

I am trying to include the document title in a heading using `scrartcl`. For some reason when I call `\maketitle`, the `\@title` variable seems to be unset and all uses of it turn up empty.

My document looks something like this (stripped to just a test case):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrpage2}
    \pagestyle{scrheadings}

    \makeatletter
    \ihead{\MakeUppercase{\@title}}
    \makeatother

    \usepackage{blindtext}

\title{my doc title}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument % headers show the document title on these pages

\maketitle

\blinddocument % these pages have an empty header

\end{document}
```

As noted, my headings show the document title fine up until the point where I call `\maketitle`, then the field is blank. I have tried re-assigning the header and even title variable after outputting the title to no-avail. How can I get my header back?

Comment: If you look up `scrartcl.cls`, you'll see that `\maketitle` wipes `\@title` (and other similar macros) globally after using them to typeset the title page.

Comment: i can't say *why* it's done, but the basic `article.cls` definitely wipes out the title and a lot more, and furthermore, disables `\title`, `\author`, and the definitions for other top matter elements.  i suspect that `scrartcl` is simply following that example.

Comment: The answer is "because", I'm afraid. `;-)` There should be a question about how keeping the title in a variable also after `\maketitle`.

Comment: @egreg -- i looked this up with `texdoc classes` (`classes.pdf` presents the annotated code for the basic latex classes), and it appears to be a matter of saving space.  (see lines 564-576.)  space was a real consideration when this code was written; it isn't any more, and i'd like to see this changed with latex3.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I agree; `\documentclass{article3}` shouldn't do this saving. Twenty years of experience with LaTeX2e and technology development also show that other metadata should be dealt with, even if not used with `\maketitle`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine `\maketitle` to save and restore a copy of `\@title`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrpage2}
    \pagestyle{scrheadings}

    \makeatletter
    \ihead{\MakeUppercase{\@title}}
    \makeatother

    \usepackage{blindtext}

\title{my doc title}

\makeatletter
  \let\svmaketitle\maketitle
  \def\maketitle{\protected@edef\saved@title{\@title}%
  \svmaketitle%
  \let\@title\saved@title}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\blinddocument % headers show the document title on these pages

\maketitle

\blinddocument % these pages have an empty header

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use a [current KOMA-Script version](http://www.komascript.de/current), at least version 3.12 which is already available for MiKTeX and TeX Live via normal package update, everything works as expected: [image]

Note: This feature depends on option version. So if you are using a deprecated option, that sets `version=first`, it doesn't work.

Comment: When did v3.12 come out (sorry I don't speak German so the site you linked to isn't helping me). I have v3.11b per the standard TexLive packages I installed just this week.

Comment: @Caleb: Around Christmas 2013. TeXLive updates have it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to patch `\maketitle` just to *remember* the title

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mytitle}{Save This Title}

\title{\mytitle}
\author{me}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
The title of this document is \mytitle.

\end{document}
```

**Edit** ... but this will not remember the title for the header.