# Emacs -- "fancy" LaTeX footer designed for regexp highlighting

Tags: header-footer, emacs

I'm looking for some assistance, please, to modify my current footer setup to make it easier to create a reliable regexp for `font-lock` highlighting.  Ideally, I'd like the bottom line of the right footer to look like: `\rfoot{Title of Document}`.  The problem is that I need a line above, but I don't know how to separate this into two different sections -- i.e., I want `\makebox[2in]{\hrulefill}\\` all by itself.  When fixed, I'd like to use a regexp similar to:

```lisp
\\(\\\\rfoot{\\)\\([^}]*\\)\\(}\\)
```

My current setup looks like this:

```
% BEGIN footer
\pagestyle{fancy}
  \cfoot{\vspace{-1mm} \ptm{-\thepage-} }
    \rfoot{\makebox[2in]{\hrulefill}\\ Title of Document }
% END
```

Which creates a right footer like this:

```
__________________________
         Title of Document
```

---

**EDIT**:  Based upon the helpful answer by @Paul Stanley, here is the revised font-lock regexp.

```lisp
(font-lock-add-keywords 'lawlist-tex-mode (list

  (list "\\(\\\\newcommand\\)\{\\(\\\\mytitle\\)\}\{\\([^}]*\\)\}"
    '(1 font-lock-keyword-face t)
    '(2 font-lock-function-name-face t)
    '(3 font-lock-warning-face t))

  (list "\\(\\\\settitle\\)\{\\([^}]*\\)\}"
    '(1 font-lock-keyword-face t)
    '(2 font-lock-warning-face t))

   ))
```

---

[image: Example]

Comment: I don't get the point -- do you ask for a special foot of a page, a special footnote on every page or a special highlighting in Emacs?

Comment: I would like the footnote to function the same as it does now, but I would like to write it differently so that the Title of Document is the only thing in between wavy brackets.  I want to separate the code that creates the line above the Title of Document.  The functionality of creating the footnote should remain the same.

Comment: When you say "footnote" do you mean "footer"? Ie, what `\rfoot` sets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I quite understand the purpose of what you are trying to achieve, but I *assume* it's something like this: You are creating a template document, and you want to have an easy way for emacs (or, presumably, a human) to identify where the title of the document--which you then use in a footer--is set.

If that's right, then one way would be to do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}%for demonstration purposes only
\newcommand{\settitle}[1]{\renewcommand{\mytitle}{#1}}% User interface
\newcommand{\mytitle}{Title Not Set!}% Stores the title

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{\makebox[2in]{\hrulefill}\\\mytitle}

\settitle{Reset Title}% Example of the user interface "in use"


\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Now all emacs/you need to do is search of `\settitle{}`, and this is the macro the user would use to set the title. You don't need to look for the `\cfoot{}` macro because the title is automatically added there.

Of course, there are many refinements to this basic scheme:

1. This uses its own macro `\settitle{}`. But it would almost certainly make more sense to "plug in" to the existing LaTeX command `title{}`, on which see [Why does \maketitle change the availability of \@title?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164225/why-does-maketitle-change-the-availability-of-title/164232)
2. This doesn't do any error checking, such as ensuring the text can sit in the box.
3. If you were writing a style or class, names such as `\mytitle` would be silly, because they could easily be used inadvertently.

And so forth.

Comment: Thank you -- I will give it a try later on this afternoon and report back.

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly.  I'll revise the question to use the correct terminology of `footer` instead of `footnote` and I'll fix the tag.  Thank you very much.